# Differentiability implies continuity (Linear Map)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8DW4.jpg)

In this proof, I'm not clear with two things:

1) how can we break $$\lim_{\mathbf x \to \mathbf a}\|{\mathbf f(\mathbf x)-\mathbf f(\mathbf a)-L(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)}\| +\|L(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)\|$$

into

$$\lim_{\mathbf x \to \mathbf a}\|{\mathbf f(\mathbf x)-\mathbf f(\mathbf a)-L(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)}\| + \lim_{\mathbf x \to \mathbf a}\|L(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)\|$$ without knowing beforehand that $$\lim_{\mathbf x \to \mathbf a}\|L(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)\|$$ exists?

2) If that is the case, how do we know that  $$\lim_{\mathbf x \to \mathbf a}\|L(\mathbf x-\mathbf a)\| =0 ?$$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The linear mapping $x\mapsto L x$ is continuous!

Comment: Linear transformations are bounded, hence continuous, on finite dimensional normed spaces, e.g., in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Could you please provide a proof for that? @lzralbu

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $L$ is linear then 
$$\lim_{x\to a}\|L(x-a)\|=\lim_{x\to a}\|L(x)-L(a)\|=\|L(a)-L(a)\|.$$

Comment: One is obligated to see what's happening in the case $\mathbb R^1\to\mathbb  R^1$ were the limit of $\frac{f(a+Dx)-f(a)}{Dx}$ give us the linear transformation $\mathbb R^1\to\mathbb R^1$ define by $$x\longmapsto f'(a)x.$$ Next for function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^1$ the linear transformation is $$(x,y)\longmapsto \frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial x}x+\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial y}y.$$ And so on.